# Uniform and non uniform convergence of infinite series

Tags: real-analysis

Does the geometric series 
1+z^2+z^3+....+z^n+....
Uniformly converge?
I made an internet search,and found it uniformly converges at ।z।<1
But in chrystal algebra vol 2
(https://archive.org/details/algebraelementar02chryuoft (see page aricle 15 page 145 example 1)
it seems something different.
Can someone explain?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not converge uniformly in $|z|<1$. It converges uniformly in $|z|\leq r$ for any $r<1$. The general term $z^{n}$ does not tend to $0$ uniformly in  $|z|<1$ as seen by taking $z=1-\frac 1 n$ so the convergence is not uniform for $|z|<1$.

Answer (score 0):

If the series converges uniformly on $|z|<1$, then for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $N$ such that $$\varepsilon>\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty z^N\right|=\left|\frac{z^N}{1-z}\right|$$ for every $|z|<1$.  This cannot be true.  Consider $z\to1^-$ on the real axis.